# C# Convert negative int to 11 bits

Tags: c#, binary, bit

I need to convert numbers in interval [–1024, 1016]. I'm converting to 11 bits like that:

```
string s = Convert.ToString(value, 2); //Convert to binary in a string

int[] bits = s.PadLeft(11, '0') // Add 0's from left
                     .Select(c => int.Parse(c.ToString())) // convert each char to int
                     .ToArray(); // Convert IEnumerable from select to Array
```

This works perfectly for signed integers [0, 1016]. But for negative integers I get 32 bits result. Do you have any idea how to convert negative integers to 11 bits array?

Comment: Can I ask : is this for display to the user? because for *general purpose* binary, you don't need to do anything much - it is already binary etc.

Comment: I'm making Discrete cosine transform (DCT) algorithm for compressing .BMP images. Now I need only 11 bits becuase numbers are in interval [–1024, 1016]. Your answer helped me a lot ty man :)

Comment: For algorithmic processing, it would be very rare to need the value as an `int[]` or something involving a `string` (normally you would do bitwise ops via `int` / `long` masks) - but - if that is what you need... fine

Comment: What do you prefer then? I need to make binary file and it needs to be compressed.

Comment: to get 11 bits? I'd stop simply at: `var valToWrite = value & 2047;`; that's it - that my 11 bits right there, which I can write as binary directly. At 11 bits, it would be very tempting to just treat it as a `short` - but if you need to write data which doesn't observe exact byte boundaries, that is fine too - you just typically end up using a back-buffer (usually an `int` is fine), and bit-ops (mostly `<<`, `>>`, `&` and `|` - occasionally `~`). This is pretty much everyday stuff to me (I deal in binary protocols a lot), and treating it as an array of bits is very .... odd.

Comment: You meant `var valToWrite = value & 2047;`?

Comment: oops! yes, I meant `&` - off-by-one error on my keyboard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only care about the first 11 bits, then just apply a mask:

```
string s = Convert.ToString(value & 2047, 2);
```

This will restrict the value to at most 11 bits - and for negative numbers, all the "unused" bits will be 1s.

For reference: 2047 is binary 0000 ... 0000 0111 1111 1111, i.e. a mask of the least significant 11 bits.